# How to avoid running of new copy of XnView MP on clicking on an image?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, xnview

If I am double clicking an image in Windows Explorer, I have XnView MP opening. For first time it's ok. But if I click another image in Windows Explorer, another copy of XnView MP is starting and so on.

Is it possible to configure XnView to reuse one single running copy on image clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure XnView MP to use only one instance:

Settings -> General -> Allow only one instance of XnView

[image]